# Mocking Cocoa objects with unavailable initializers in unit tests

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking, core-bluetooth

I am building an iOS app with Swift that uses apple's CoreBluetooth framework to communicate with peripherals via Bluetooth Low Energy. In the effort of unit testing a custom controller which implements the *CBCentralManagerDelegate* and *CBPeripheralDelegate* protocols, I am providing a **test double subclassed from CBCentralManager** to mimic the behaviour of the CoreBluetooth API. The delegate callbacks of the controller are invoked at appropriate times.

So far this has been working pretty well. But when it comes to calling the *CBPeripheralDelegate* callbacks, a *CBPeripheral* needs to be passed in. Usually, I would just fake the component providing my own subclass or mock an instance of *CBPeripheral*.

**Here's the catch**: The designated initializer of *CBPeripheral* in the underlying Objective-C library is marked as unavailable which prevents me from instantiating a *CBPeripheral* in my faked *CBCentralManager* and passing it as an argument to the *CBPeripheralDelegate* under test. (XCode leaves me with a compiler error.)

So far I have tried providing a custom initializer in my fake subclass (which doesn't work because I have to call the unavailable designated init eventually), overriding the initializer with an extension (which is not allowed apparently) and calling the selector (init) with the Objective-C runtime like I don't give a shit that it's unavailable. The last approach seems the most promising, but isn't really working and leaves me with unmanaged objects of the wrong type (my test class).

I've definitely hit a roadblock here and would be extremely glad for any input on

1. **instantiating a *CBPeripheral* despite init() being unavailable**
2. **a different approach for unit testing the *CBPeripheralDelegate***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself by pursuing the objc-runtime idea and creating an Object Factory in Objective-C, that calls the initializer's implementation by its pointer to ignore the unavailable mark.

For further information see:
http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/05/instantiating-classes-by-name-in-swift/
(This is not working anymore in current Swift but can be easily adapted)

Answer (score 0):

### Swift Version

Mock your `CBCentralManager`

```
final private class BluetootManagerMock: CBCentralManager {
    var mockState: CBManagerState = .poweredOff
 
    override var state: CBManagerState {
        mockState
    }
}
```

Then just call the delegate in the class you are testing.

`yourClassToBeTests.centralManagerDidUpdateState(BluetootManagerMock)`

with this you'll mock the delegate mock easily.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work with protocols to unit test the Bluetooth framework:

```
protocol CentralManager: AnyObject {
    var delegate: CBCentralManagerDelegate? { get set }
    var state: CBManagerState { get }

    func scanForPeripherals(withServices serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID]?, options: [String : Any]?)
    func connect(_ peripheral: Peripheral, options: [String : Any]?)
}

extension CentralManager {
    func scanForPeripherals(withServices serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID]?, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
        scanForPeripherals(withServices: serviceUUIDs, options: options)
    }

    func connect(_ peripheral: Peripheral, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
        connect(peripheral, options: options)
    }
}

extension CBCentralManager: CentralManager {
    func connect(_ peripheral: Peripheral, options: [String : Any]?) {
        guard let peripheral = peripheral as? CBPeripheral else { return }
        connect(peripheral, options: options)
    }
}

protocol CentralManagerDelegate: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CentralManager)

    func centralManager(
        _ central: CentralManager,
        didDiscover peripheral: Peripheral,
        advertisementData: [String : Any],
        rssi RSSI: NSNumber
    )

    func centralManager(_ central: CentralManager, didConnect peripheral: Peripheral)
}

protocol Peripheral: AnyObject {
    var state: CBPeripheralState { get }
    var delegate: CBPeripheralDelegate? { get set }
    var services: [CBService]? { get }

    func discoverServices(_ serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID]?)
}

extension CBPeripheral: Peripheral {}

protocol PeripheralDelegate: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: Peripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)
}
```

You need to conform your delegate of the CentralManagerDelegate & PeripheralDelegate, but also CBCentralManagerDelegate & CBPeripheralDelegate. I route the CBCentralManagerDelegate & CBPeripheralDelegate to the other delegates, like this:

```
/// Connect the CBCentralManagerDelegate to CentralManagerDelegate.
extension NewBluetoothHelper: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        centralManagerDidUpdateState(central as CentralManager)
    }

    func centralManager(
        _ central: CBCentralManager,
        didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
        advertisementData: [String : Any],
        rssi RSSI: NSNumber
    ) {
        centralManager(
            central as CentralManager,
            didDiscover: peripheral as Peripheral,
            advertisementData: advertisementData,
            rssi: RSSI
        )
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        centralManager(central as CentralManager, didConnect: peripheral as Peripheral)
    }
}

/// Connect the CBPeripheralDelegate to PeripheralDelegate.
extension NewBluetoothHelper: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        self.peripheral(peripheral as Peripheral, didDiscoverServices: error)
    }
}
```

With the above it is possible to mock the CentralManager and the Peripheral in your tests.

A problem you might encounter is to set the services on the Peripheral mock, as they need to be of [CBService]. My solution was to initialize a subclass of NSObject in the following way for mocking:

```
let serviceClass = NSClassFromString("CBService") as? NSObject.Type
let service = serviceClass?.init() as! CBService
service.setValue(CBUUID(string: "0x180D"), forKey: "UUID") //
```

Now your mock implementation of Peripheral can just set a `var services: [CBSservice]? = [service]`